# Google Sites : Sharing & Permissions on pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have many pages on my a google sites , those pages are not quite related and I have to give access for each page to a specific list of users.
Google only offer me to add users to Top-level page , so I need to add all users then for each page I'll need to manually chose from all users added on top level who stays and who delete . 
This seems that it will take a lot of time , I have like 30 pages and more than 120 user so ...

I already have the lists for each page , I want just for each page add a list of users .

Answer (score 1):

there is currently no way using the sites api. google sites does supoort page level permissions for years now but unfortunately the api was never updated by google to allow this.